# Can't use AWT SystemTray

Tags: java, awt

```
import java.awt.*;

public class TrayIconDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, java.net.MalformedURLException {
        if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            TrayIconDemo td = new TrayIconDemo();
            td.displayTray();
        } else {
            System.err.println("System tray not supported!");
        }
    }

    public void displayTray() throws AWTException, java.net.MalformedURLException {
        //Obtain only one instance of the SystemTray object
        SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

        //If the icon is a file
        Image image = Toolkit.getToolkit().createImage("icon.png");
        //Alternative (if the icon is on the classpath):
        //Image image = Toolkit.getToolkit().createImage(getClass().getResource("icon.png"));
        TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Tray Demo");
        //Let the system resizes the image if needed
        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
        //Set tooltip text for the tray icon
        trayIcon.setToolTip("System tray icon demo");
        tray.add(trayIcon);
        trayIcon.displayMessage("Hello, World", "notification demo", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
    }
}
```

When I hover over SystemTray or TrayIcon I get the following message:

```
Usage of API documented as @since 1.6+ less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection finds all usages of methods that have @since tag in their documentation.  This may be useful when development is performed under newer SDK version as the target platform for production.
```

The classes are red-underlined. I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-bit, SP1. What could be the problem?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java 1.8

Comment: What IDE......?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4

Comment: Are you using a Maven based project?  It defaults source compatibility to Java 1.5. The only issue I have is with `Toolkit.getToolkit()` which should be `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()`

Comment: It's a gradle project. Changing to Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit() fixed that one error. SystemTray and TrayIcon classes are still red.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, but something wrong with your project configuration in your IDE.

1. Make sure that your build tool is using the correct version of Java. For the System Tray, you need at least Java 1.6. Some build tools still default to quite old versions of Java, for example, Maven defaults to 1.5. So, make sure that you've selected a version of Java in your build tool which is new enough.
2. Make sure that your IDE has the same settings as your build tool. If your build tool is supported by your IDE, reimport your configuration from your build tool. If not, manually setup the configuration.

In the comments of your question, you have written that you are using IntelliJ IDEA. In IntelliJ IDEA, you can check the settings this way:

1. Go to File -> Project Structure.
2. There, in Project Settings -> Project, make sure that the Project SDK and the Project language level are new enough, at least 1.6.
3. There, in Project Settings -> Modules, Dependencies, make sure that the Module SDK is new enough.

Hope that helps.